# Handle change on Autocomplete Component from material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use `Autocomplete` component for input tags. I'm trying to get the tags and save them on a state so I can later save them on the database. I'm using functions instead of classes in react. I did try with `onChange`, but I didn't get any result.

```
<div style={{ width: 500 }}>
  <Autocomplete
    multiple
    options={autoComplete}
    filterSelectedOptions
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.tags}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        className={classes.input}
        {...params}
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="Favorites"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
      />
    )}
  />
</div>;
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As Yuki already mentioned, make sure you did use the `onChange` function properly. It receives two parameters. According to the documentation:

> **Signature**: `function(event: object, value: any) => void`.
>
> `event`: The event source of the callback
>
> `value`: null (The value/values within the Autocomplete component).

Here's an example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class Tags extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tags: []
    };
    this.onTagsChange = this.onTagsChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTagsChange = (event, values) => {
    this.setState({
      tags: values
    }, () => {
      // This will output an array of objects
      // given by Autocompelte options property.
      console.log(this.state.tags);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          multiple
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
          onChange={this.onTagsChange}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              variant="standard"
              label="Multiple values"
              placeholder="Favorites"
              margin="normal"
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: 'Pulp Fiction', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King', year: 2003 },
  { title: 'The Good, the Bad and the Ugly', year: 1966 },
  { title: 'Fight Club', year: 1999 },
  { title: 'The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring', year: 2001 },
  { title: 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back', year: 1980 },
  { title: 'Forrest Gump', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'Inception', year: 2010 },
];
```

Comment: Good catch! using values instead of event.target.value resolved the issue

Comment: @Germmand Does onChange always include the value parameter? Or is this specific to the MUI Autocomplete component? Where did you find this documentation? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 16):

I needed to hit my api on every input change to get my tags from backend!

Use Material-ui onInputChange if you want to get your suggested tags on every input change!

```
this.state = {
  // labels are temp, will change every time on auto complete
  labels: [],
  // these are the ones which will be send with content
  selectedTags: [],
}
}

//to get the value on every input change
onInputChange(event,value){
console.log(value)
//response from api
.then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        labels: res
      })
    })

}

//to select input tags
onSelectTag(e, value) {
this.setState({
  selectedTags: value
})
}


            <Autocomplete
            multiple
            options={top100Films}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
            onChange={this.onSelectTag} // click on the show tags
            onInputChange={this.onInputChange} //** on every input change hitting my api**
            filterSelectedOptions
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                variant="standard"
                label="Multiple values"
                placeholder="Favorites"
                margin="normal"
                fullWidth
              />
```

Comment: How did you show the options that were fetched on the API call on onInputChange function in the dropdown? In my case, unless I close the dropdown and open it, options don't get populated

Comment: @Aditya I had the same problem with closing and reopening. I found the solution was to override the default filterOptions. Try adding filterOptions={(options, state) => options} as a prop to your <Autocomplete> component.

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure you used `onChange` correctly?

`onChange` **signature**: `function(event: object, value: any) => void`

Comment: does onChange always include the value parameter? Or is this specific to the MUI Autocomplete component? Where did you find this documentation? I cannot find it.

Comment: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/

Answer (score 9):

@Dworo

If someone has a problem with displaying a selected item from the dropdown in the Input field,

I found a workaround, basically, you have to bind an `inputValue` at `onChage` for both `Autocomplete` and `TextField`.

```
const [input, setInput] = useState('');

<Autocomplete
  options={suggestions}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
  inputValue={input}
  onChange={(e,v) => setInput(v)}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" onChange={({ target }) => setInput(target.value)} variant="outlined" fullWidth />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: Actually one has to use onInputChange, not onChange in 2023...

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to update my state when I select an option from the autocomplete. I had a global onChange handler that manages for all inputs

```
         const {name, value } = event.target;
         setTukio({
          ...tukio,
          [name]: value,
        });
```

That updates the object dynamically based on the name of the field. But on the Autocomplete the name returns blank. So I changed the handler from `onChange` to `onSelect`. Then either create a separate function to handle the change or as in my case added an if statement to check if the name is not passed.

```
// This one will set state for my onSelect handler of the autocomplete 
     if (!name) {
      setTukio({
        ...tukio,
        tags: value,
      });
     } else {
      setTukio({
        ...tukio,
        [name]: value,
      });
    }
```

The above approach works if u have a single autocomplete. If you have multiple u can pass a custom function like below

```
<Autocomplete
    options={tags}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.tagName}
    id="tags"
    name="tags"
    autoComplete
    includeInputInList
    onSelect={(event) => handleTag(event, 'tags')}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} hint="koo, ndama nyonya" label="Tags" margin="normal" />}
        />

// The handler 
const handleTag = ({ target }, fieldName) => {
    const { value } = target;
    switch (fieldName) {
      case 'tags':
        console.log('Value ',  value)
        // Do your stuff here
        break;
      default:
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

I have an array of objects of type:

```
{
   id: someId,
   label: someLabel,
}
```

let's call this array "items". And use a formState object, like this:

```
   const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
      idPuntoVenta: '',
      nomPuntoVenta: '',
      selected: items[0],
    });
```

And defined the Autocomplete component like this:

```
<Autocomplete
    disablePortal
    id="salesPoint"
    options={sortedSalesPoints}
    value={selected}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            selected: newValue,
            idPuntoVenta: newValue?.id,
        });
    }}
    inputValue={nomPuntoVenta}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setFormState({
            ...formState,
            nomPuntoVenta: newInputValue,
        });
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            className="form-control"
            size="small"
            label="Punto de venta"
            required
        />
    )}
/>;
```

The important thing here (and the one that took me a while) is to understand that the {value} property of the Autocomplete component is an object of the same type of the ones stored in the array "items"

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use the 'setFieldValue' of the formik
Just an example of an autocomplete handling multiple values

```html
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{
    roles: [],
  }}
  onSubmit={}
  validationSchema={someSchema}
>
  {({
    values,
    errors,
    touched,
    handleChange,
    handleSubmit,
    handleBlur,
    setFieldValue,
  }) => (
    <form noValidate>
      <Autocomplete
        id="role-name"
        options={"some Array of options"}
        value={values.roles}
        multiple
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option?.name}
        onChange={(e, value) => setFieldValue("role", value)} //Here
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" name="role" />
        )}
      />
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>;
```