# Material UI auto complete value and onChange

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm trying to implement auto complete on Material UI component,

this is their code :

```
  <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
      )}
    />
```

the full code you can find here :https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/autocomplete/ComboBox.js

my question is, how do I add onChange and be able to show the value that was selected, as we do in Input we just show value={} but in here it does not work, and I cannot find anything about it in the documentation, thanks for the help!

Comment: See my example (with `onChange` and `value` props on the `Autocomplete` element) in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035788/material-ui-autocomplete-can-tags-be-created-on-events-aside-from-enter-event/59038435#59038435

Answer (score 1):

Answer for your question is here :

[Usage of onChange with AutoComplete Material Ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58684579/handle-change-on-autocomplete-component-from-material-ui)

You should use `onChange` properly. The value lays on the second parameter of the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the value of the textfield I have inserted the following `onChange={e=>changeHandler(e.target.value)}`

```
// in Hooks area
const changeHandler = value => {
    console.log(value); // value should be here
}

  <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField onChange={e=>changeHandler(e.target.value)} {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work, I cannot see the selected value in the input, nor the item passed down to the function, the changeHandler(event) was flagged for wrong syntax too.

Comment: Apologies - it is revised please try now

Comment: thanks for the help but it does not work, if you select the value, you do not see it as "selected" in the input ( it remains blank), plus the console log does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Autocomplete
   onChange={(e,v) => console.log(v)}
   options={top100Films}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
   renderOption={(props, option) => (
      <li {...props}>
         {option.title}
      </li>
   )}
   renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} required />}
/>
```

I'm using onChange props
`onChange={(e,v) => console.log(v)}`