# Reactjs - Update options by hitting API on every input change in Autocomplete component (Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am a beginner in Reactjs. I want to create an Autocomplete component where on every input change the API is hit and the options are updated accordingly. I am using the Autocomplete component provided by Material UI. As I understand, the example given [here](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#Asynchronous.js) hits an API once and filters it locally. I tried using the InputChange props provided by material component. Also I found this anser - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59751227/8090336. But can't figure out the right way.

```
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import {CircularProgress} from "@material-ui/core";
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const SelectField = ({inputLabel}) => {
    const [ open, setOpen ] = React.useState(false);
    const [ options, setOptions ] = React.useState([]);
    const [ inputValue, setInputValue ] = React.useState("");
    const loading = open && options.length === 0;

    const onInputChange = debounce((event, value) => {
        console.log("OnInputChange",value);
        setInputValue(value);
        (async() => {
            const response = await fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q='+inputValue);
            console.log("API hit again")
            let movies = await response.json();

            if(movies !== undefined) {
                setOptions(movies);
                console.log(movies)
            }
        })();
    }, 1500);

    return (
        <Autocomplete
            style={{ width:300 }}
            open={open}
            onOpen={() => {
              setOpen(true);
            }}
            onClose={() => {
              setOpen(false);
            }}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.show.name}
            onInputChange={onInputChange}
            options={options}
            loading={loading}
            renderInput={(params) => (<TextField
                {...params}
                label={inputLabel}
                variant="outlined"
                InputProps={{
                  ...params.InputProps,
                  endAdornment: (
                      <React.Fragment>
                          {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />: null }
                          {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                      </React.Fragment>
                  ),
                }}
              />
            )}
        />
    );
}

export default SelectField;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had faced this problem I manually called the API when ever the user types in. find the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tyrqz?file=/demo.js:72-2075) for the sandbox. Check the onChange prop for the textfield rendered inside the autocomplete

```
// *https://www.registers.service.gov.uk/registers/country/use-the-api*
import fetch from "cross-fetch";
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";


export default function Asynchronous() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
  const loading = open && options.length === 0;


  const onChangeHandle = async value => {
// this default api does not support searching but if you use google maps or some other use the value and post to get back you reslut and then set it using setOptions 
    console.log(value);

    const response = await fetch(
      "https://country.register.gov.uk/records.json?page-size=5000"
    );

    const countries = await response.json();
    setOptions(Object.keys(countries).map(key => countries[key].item[0]));
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!open) {
      setOptions([]);
    }
  }, [open]);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="asynchronous-demo"
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => {
        setOpen(true);
      }}
      onClose={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      options={options}
      loading={loading}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Asynchronous"
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={ev => {
            // dont fire API if the user delete or not entered anything
            if (ev.target.value !== "" || ev.target.value !== null) {
              onChangeHandle(ev.target.value);
            }
          }}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            endAdornment: (
              <React.Fragment>
                {loading ? (
                  <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} />
                ) : null}
                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              </React.Fragment>
            )
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this fully answers @gowtham-bhat's question.  They are using a search API and passing an updated querystring value as the user types (notice the use of debounce).  Instead the solution you provided instead caches all the results beforehand and filter in the UI.

Comment: @ChrisBricker Yes, I have answered how you can call the API on every value change in the text field. building query string could be different for different cases. 

onChangeHandle function there a value passed, that is the user-entered value use it to build your query string.