# Material-ui Autocomplete - onChange not triggered when updating value in onHighlightChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been working on an extended version of Material UI's Autocomplete where I am implementing a feature that allows the user to move the option to the input via keyboard events (Arrow key up + down). The user should then be allowed to select one of the options via the `ENTER` key.

For some reason, the `onChange` event is not triggered and I am kind of puzzled to understand why this happens.

```
export default function Autocompleter() {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState(null);

  const handleInputChange = (event, option, reason) => {
    console.log('On input change triggered');
  };

  const handleOnChange = (event, value, reason) => {
    console.log('On change triggered! ');
  };

  const handleHighlightChange = (event, option, reason) => {
    if (option && reason === 'keyboard') {
      setInput(option);
    }
  };

  const handleFilterOptions = (currentOptions) => currentOptions;

  const handleGetOptionsLabel = (option) => {
    return option.label;
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      freeSolo={true}
      value={input}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      options={top100Films}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
      includeInputInList={true}
      onHighlightChange={handleHighlightChange}
      getOptionLabel={handleGetOptionsLabel}
      filterOptions={handleFilterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Here is also a working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rsodyc?file=index.tsx,App.tsx,Autocompleter.tsx

**NOTE:** This is a light example of my original code, but it should be enough to address the issue.

There are a few things I tried such as using `inputValue` in combination with the `onHighlightChange` but this does not seem to work either.

`includeInputInList` seemed to be the solution according to the doc, but it does nothing? Does anyone understand what it is supposed to do and is it helpful in my case?

**UPDATE:**

Updating the `input` state in `onHighlightChange` breaks the `onChange`. Unfortunately, I do want to update the `input` every time the user highlights an option via keyboard events.

Thank you for any kind of help and idea

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59751227/5761648

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I found that to my knowledge its not possible to check for a "Enter" key on the `handleHighlightChange` function I've come up with this.

`highlightedInput` is a seperate state for the highlighted value, this way you can keep track of the currently highlighted input. We set this in the `handleHighlightChange` after our checks.

We want to change our `input` state when we click `Enter`, normally when clicking the `Enter` key the dropdown closes. To handle this we can create a state for the `open` state of the dropdown. For this we need a `handleOpen` and a custom close handler `handleOnclose` here we can set the currently highlighted value (`highlightedInput`) to the actual `input` state.

```js
const [input, setInput] = React.useState(null);
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);
const [highlightedInput, setHighlightedInput] = React.useState(null);

const handleOpen = () => {
  setIsOpen(true);
};

const handleOnClose = (event, option, reason, details) => {
  if (option && event.key === "Enter") {
    setInput(highlightedInput);
  }
  setIsOpen(false);
};

const handleInputChange = (event, option, reason) => {
  console.log("On input change triggered");
};

const handleOnChange = (event, value, reason) => {
  console.log("On change triggered!");
};

const handleHighlightChange = (event, option, reason) => {
  if (option && reason === "keyboard") {
    setHighlightedInput(option);
  }
};

const handleFilterOptions = (currentOptions) => currentOptions;

const handleGetOptionsLabel = (option) => {
  return option.label;
};
```

**Note** that we changed the `value` from the AutoComplete to the `highlightedInput` instead of `input`.

```js
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      freeSolo={true}
      open={isOpen}
      onOpen={handleOpen}
      onClose={handleOnClose}
      value={highlightedInput}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      onInputChange={handleInputChange}
      options={top100Films}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.label === value.label}
      includeInputInList={true}
      onHighlightChange={handleHighlightChange}
      getOptionLabel={handleGetOptionsLabel}
      filterOptions={handleFilterOptions}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
    <div style={{ height: "200px" }}></div>
    {input?.label}
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

[Live version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-6bfenk?file=index.tsx,App.tsx,Autocompleter.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for your approch on the problem! Although it's not the solution I had in mind, it works and that's what counts :)

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` handler runs when the user selects an option from the drop down. Seams that you want the `onInputChange` event. That one fires when you type in the input field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I was not clear enough on my case. `onChange` is triggered when you select an option either via mouse click or via the keyboard event  `ENTER`. I want the user to use the arrow keys to choose his preferred option and then use ENTER.